# mySQL update column with concat of another table

Tags: mysql, concatenation

experience> novice, 68/m

MySQL> 5.5.46-0+deb7u1

Database> apparel

There are two tables> femme PRIMARY = id, colors PRIMARY = c_id

I need the following table `femme` to be modified (or updated ...)

```
id      Name        Fav_Colors      City        

 1      Joe         red             Athens  

 1      Rea         grey            Rome
```

table `colors` must contribute it's data to table femme by replacing the above colors (flavored with some  tags):

```
c_id    Name        Pref_Color                  City        City_color 

 1      Joe         yellow                      Athens      blue        

 2      Rea         green                       Rome        black
```

When `femme` is TRUNCATE(d) at the beginning everything is ok resulting the modified `femme` table bellow:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `femme`;

REPLACE INTO `femme`(`id`, `name`, `Fav_Colors`, `City`)

SELECT
CONCAT ('

c_id,
Name,
<div>', colors.Pref_Color, ' - ', colors.City_color,'"</div>',
City
')
from colors;


id      Name        Fav_Colors                      City        

 1      Joe         <div>yellow - blue</div>        Athens  

 1      Rea         <div>green - black</div>        Rome
```

I just need to do it by replacing only the `Fav_Colors` column, but the following is not working:

```
REPLACE INTO `femme`(`Fav_Colors`) 
SELECT 
CONCAT ('
<div>', colors.Pref_Color, ' - ', colors.City_color,'"</div>'
')
from colors;
```

Would you please assist to find a way to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Could it be because of the double single quote after `</div>`?

Comment: Thank you Tomaso. You are right, the double single quote is not needed. It was missplaced during editing of this request, but it is only a typo error. My problem is that even with an empty CONCAT('  '), the specific field is not updated if the whole table is not TRUNCATE(d). I need to replace the contents of a single field (Fav_Colors) only and leave the rest of columns untuched. Sorry for my English, I'm a mediterranean (GR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a simple `UPDATE`.
Does `femme.id` always correspond to `colors.c_id`? If so, you can do:

```
UPDATE femme
JOIN colors ON femme.id = colors.c_id
SET femme.Fav_Colors =
CONCAT('<div>', colors.Pref_Color, ' - ', colors.City_color,'</div>')
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable assistance and the working solution given Tomaso :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it was helpful.